# Moving all files from one folder to upper folder

Tags: linux, mv

I was searching the answer to question how to move files from one folder to upper folder and nowhere I have not found the answer `mv name/* .`

Why I can't use this to moving files to upper folder? The most voted option is `mv * .[^.]* ..`, so my question is, why `mv name/* .` is wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). `mv name/* .` only matches files in the folder that don't start with a dot (`.`). You can change that behavior by setting [dotglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) in a bash shell:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Now, you can use `mv name/* .` to move ALL files and folders.

As example is have a folder containing two files: `file` and `.file`:

```
$ echo *
file
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
file .file
```

**Notice:** `mv * .[^.]* destination` works without the dotglob, because it matches first `*` and second `.[^.]*` which matches files/folders starting with a dot (not `.` and `..`).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also match `.*` not just `*` if the archive contained dot-files.

Also add `&& rmdir folder` to the end o that to remove the now extraneous folder. 
This is save because it will only run if the mv returns success AND because rmdir will not remove a non-empty directory.